# Android get bounds of rotated,scaled text on canvas

Tags: android, textview, android-canvas

I have a textview with some text. Textview have touch events, so user can rotate, scale and translate text. For translation, rotation
and scaling i'm using canvas. Canvas is doing this inside onDraw() function. Now i want to have outer bounds of text when it is scaled or rotated, can anybody help me. 
Thanks in Advance.

I try this piece of code to translate,rotate and scale text on canvas:

```
canvas.scale(fScaledFactorForTextview,fScaledFactorForTextview,getTextWidth() / (2.0f *   getLineCount()) + fTranslationX, (getTextSize() * getLineCount()) / 2.0f + fTranslationY);
canvas.rotate(fDegrees, getTextWidth() / (2.0f * getLineCount()) + fTranslationX,    (getTextSize() * getLineCount()) / 2.0f + fTranslationY);
canvas.translate(fTranslationX,fTranslationY);
```

Comment: if you say outer bound you mean so it wont crop the text when rotated or traslated?

Comment: Yes i want outer bounds, and it is not cropping text, we can scale to any factor by scaling, rotating by our two fingures via on touch events.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's easier to do this if you use a matrix, rather than direct rotate and scale calls like this.  If you use a matrix, you can just apply those same adjustments to the matrix.  Then you can easily translate any point from normal Cartesion coordinates to the altered coordinates by multiplying the coordinates by that matrix.  Matrix even provides the mapPoints function to do that.

Comment: I am able to do this successfully with matrix for Image. Now i can do this from text as well and How? Because i did not get success from matrix for text so i moved to canvas operation.

Comment: Use setMatrix to set the matrix and it should work.  I believe that all the canvas rotate and similar functions do is scale the matrix set by setMatrix anyway (which obviously defaults to identity).  But keeping the matrix yourself allows you to precalculate before drawing and use it at other times when it's convenient.