# Zoom-in, zoom-out and rotation of TextView in android

Tags: android, touch-event

i create app for display text on screen and user can drag and drop,zoom-in and zoom-out and rotation of text when touch.

i aslo using gesture detecter class but it only for zoom-in zoom-out work. it does not rotation and drag.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float size = mDragText.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

        float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));

        float product = size * factor;
        Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
        myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

        size = myTextView.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));
        return true;
    }
}
```

so, give me any kind of solution for that problem.

Comment: see https://github.com/pskink/android-gesture-detectors

Comment: @pskink this is only for imageView and required for textview

Comment: what is only for ImageView?

Comment: github example works on imagView and i am talking about textView

Comment: detectors have nothing to do with any view,  they just detect some multitouch gestures

Comment: i know but it is posible with textView or not?

Comment: sure you can do that, just override onDraw: call Canvas.concat and then call super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elesh you can do this by matrix and canvas check out this question

[Android get bounds of rotated,scaled text on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858283/android-get-bounds-of-rotated-scaled-text-on-canvas)